# Prevent robots from indexing a restricted access sub domain

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, subdomain, http-status-code-403, robots.txt

I have a sub domain setup for which i return a 403 for all but one IP. 
I also want to avoid the site being indexed by search engines, which is why I added a robots.txt to the root of my sub domain.

However, since I return a 403 on every request to that subdomain, the crawler will also receive a 403 when they request the robots.txt file.

According to [google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq?hl=en#h1c), if a robots,txt returns a 403, it will still try and crawl the site.

Is there anyway around this? Keen to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With robots.txt you can disallow *crawling*, not *indexing*.

You can disallow indexing (but not crawling) with the HTML `meta`-`robots` or the corresponding HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`.

So you have three options:

- **Whitelist `/robots.txt` so that it answers with 200.** Conforming bots won’t crawl anything on your host (except the robots.txt), but they may index URLs if they find them somehow (e.g., if linked from another site).

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /
  ```
- **Add a `meta`-`robots` element to each page.** Conforming bots may crawl, but they won’t index. But this does only work for HTML documents.

  ```
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
  ```
- **Send a `X-Robots-Tag` header for each document.** Conforming bots may crawl, but they won’t index.

  ```
  X-Robots-Tag: noindex
  ```

(Sending 403 for each request may in itself be a strong signal that there’s nothing interesting to see; but what to make of it would depend on the bot, of course.)

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks ! (A bit late with thanking but better late than never!)